# File Parser - How to Read Lines

Tags: c++, parsing

I'm trying to implement a line scan conversion in OpenGL from stdin that lists line end points like so:

```
L 0, 0, 150, 150
C 200 300
L -20, 40, 22, 55
[...]
Z
```

Where the [...] is just more of the same, and the Z character is a convenient termination operator, though end of file may also work. L and C denote sets of points/data that will be used to draw lines/circles respectively.

Here is my parser in progress (libraries for all functions in use included):

```
void parseFile ()
{

ifstream lines;
lines.open("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/lines.txt");
string currentLine = 0;

while(getline(lines, currentLine))
{

    switch(currentLine[0] = 'L')
    {
    string coordLine = currentLine.substr(1, currentLine.length());
    while (getline(lines, coordLine, ',')){
        for(int i = 0; i < coordLine.length(); i++) {
            char* c = 0;
            *(c+i) = coordLine[i];
            atoi(c);
            cout << c;
        }
        return;
    }

    }

    switch(currentLine[0] = 'Z') {
    break;
    }

    switch(currentLine[0] = 'C') {
    //Similar implementation to line case when resolved
    }

}

}
```

I am trying to read the integer values only (sans comma and L/C/Z delimiters) into arrays, so I can then simply use them for drawing in OpenGL. However, I am having some difficulty with reading and storing. As you can see, my algorithmic approach is to switch based on the alphabetical character at the beginning of the lines, and then reduce the line string to the remaining values and try to work through them. However, I am having an impossible time trying to convert the values into integers from the coordinate line I have defined.

So in short, my questions are: Does my approach make sense? What potentially could be a simpler way to store these coordinates for OpenGL drawing use than the separate array approach I plan to implement? Finally, how can I convert the lines of my file into the appropriate integers for storage?

Comment: `*(c+i) = coordLine[i];` but c is null??

Comment: `string currentLine = 0;` <= that's an instant crash! No need to initialize your string it will be empty by default.

Comment: Ahh, fair point @Galik. A total byproduct of my confused brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your current code. I have provided an example of how I might go about parsing this:

```
void parseFile()
{
    ifstream lines;
    lines.open("test.txt");
    string currentLine; // Do NOT make this = 0 it will cause a crash!

    while(getline(lines, currentLine))
    {
        // no need to process blank lines
        // this also fixes potential crash
        // when you check the first character
        if(currentLine.empty())
            continue;

        // recommend std::stringstream for parsing strings
        std::istringstream iss(currentLine); // turn line into stream

        char type; // L, C or Z

        if(!(iss >> type)) // ALWAYS check for errors
            continue;

        // Your switch was incorrectly formed
        switch(type)
        {
            case 'L':
            {
                char comma;
                int x0, y0, x1, y1;

                // read the numbers skipping the commas
                if(!(iss >> x0 >> comma >> y0 >> comma >> x1 >> comma >> y1))
                {
                    // ALWAYS check for errors
                    std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to read L: " << currentLine << std::endl;
                    continue;
                }

                // do something with coordinates (x0, y0, x1, y1) here
                std::cout << "(" << x0 << ", " << y0 << ", " << x1 << ", " << y1 << ")" << '\n';

                break;
            }
            case 'C':
            {
                break;
            }
            case 'Z':
            {
                break;
            }
            default:
                std::cerr << "ERROR: Unrecognized type: " << currentLine << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Don't leave error checking as an after thought.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is a great answer! Good point about error checking - it's always best practice, and I shouldn't have left it until the end, or I wouldn't have had all these ridiculous initialization errors. I'll still have to give the effective storage problem some thought, but you helped me refine the switch statement for the letters and verified my thinking, which I thank you very much for! Cheers!

Comment: Running it tells me errors exist in the project, but if I ignore them and run anyway, it prints as expected. Any idea why? I am using Eclipse IDE on Windows 7. Tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, no red underlined errors that I can see.

Comment: @Rome_Leader Eclipse doesn't remove previous errors from the "Problems" window. You have to select them and delete them manually. Maybe that's what's happening? Try selecting all in the "Problems" window and deleting them.

Comment: I see now that it is not finding the includes anymore... Such as OpenGL libraries. That is strange is they had worked before in other projects, and I configured them the same way (Project Properties -> C/C++ General/Paths and Symbols). Nothing has changed to my knowledge, but now they all give the same error on build (they still launch fine when I ignore the "error"). I'll try restarting Eclipse.

Comment: Hmmm... After reopening, the warnings persist in the Problems tab, but the error pop up no longer persists.